# Using the raw expression Laravel 4

Tags: sql, laravel-4

please tell me how to do this off correct query

```
select @a:=POW(max(count_votes), 1/10) from users;

select id,name,raiting, count_votes, ((LOG(@a,count_votes))+raiting)/2 as actual_raiting from users order by actual_raiting desc ;
```

tried like this

```
$rating = DB::statement('select @a:=POW(max(count_votes), 1/10) from users;

select id,name,raiting, count_votes, ((LOG(@a,count_votes))+raiting)/2 as actual_raiting from users order by actual_raiting desc; ');

return $rating;
```

and

```
$rating = DB::table('users')
                    ->select(DB::raw('*, @a:=POW(max(count_votes), 1/10) '))
                    ->select(DB::raw('*,raiting, count_votes, ((LOG(@a,count_votes))+raiting)/2 as actual_raiting'))
                    ->orderBy("actual_raiting")
                    ->get();

    return $rating;
```

what am I doing wrong ?

ps:/sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting it all in one select:

```
$rating = DB::table('users')
            ->select(DB::raw('*, raiting, count_votes, ((LOG(POW(max(count_votes), 1/10),count_votes))+raiting)/2 as actual_raiting'))
            ->orderBy("actual_raiting")
            ->get();
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this worked please [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If not please tell me what I should change/edit or add your own answer :)

Comment: And how do I get only the field 'actual_rating'?
he told me to return all data

Comment: Just remove `*, raiting, count_votes, `. If you want `actual_rating` as an array you can do `lists('actual_rating')` instead of `get()`

Comment: `$rating = DB::table('users')
            ->select(DB::raw('((LOG(POW(max(count_votes), 1/10),count_votes))+raiting)/2 as actual_raiting'))
            ->orderBy("actual_raiting")
            ->lists('actual_rating');`
not working
returns empty

Comment: Oh sorry `lists('actual_raiting')`. However you probably mean `rating` and not `raiting`

Comment: not that you will excuse me
that's my fault
thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$rating1 = DB::select(DB::raw('select @a:=POW(max(count_votes), 1/10) from users'));

$rating2 = DB::select(DB::raw('select id,name,raiting, count_votes, ((LOG(@a,count_votes))+raiting)/2 as actual_raiting from users order by actual_raiting desc; '));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($rating1);
print_r($rating2);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select id,name,raiting, count_votes, ((LOG(@a,count_votes))+raiting)/2 as actual' at line 3 (SQL: select @a:=POW(max(count_votes), 1/10) from users; select id,name,raiting, count_votes, ((LOG(@a,count_votes))+raiting)/2 as actual_raiting from users order by actual_raiting desc; )

Comment: So, it means that your SQL query is incorrect, try to run it in phpmyAdmin, rectify that and try again.

Comment: Try to call 1 query at a time.